# Summarising data in one data frame based on values in another

Tags: r, date, join, summary

I have two data frames, one with details of survey dates and one with instances of individuals being recorded. As follows:

```
Records <- data.frame("Location"=c("A","A","B","C","C","C","D"),
                      "Date"= c("09/01/2017","12/01/2017","20/01/2017","06/06/2017","03/06/2017","19/01/2017","02/01/2017"),
                      "Individuals"= c(3,2,6,4,0,1,6))
Surveys <- data.frame("Location"=c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D"),
                     "Start"= c(rep("01/01/2017",length=4),rep("01/06/2017",length=4)),
                      "End"= c(rep("01/02/2017",length=4),rep("01/07/2017",length=4)))

> Surveys
  Location      Start        End
1        A 01/01/2017 01/02/2017
2        B 01/01/2017 01/02/2017
3        C 01/01/2017 01/02/2017
4        D 01/01/2017 01/02/2017
5        A 01/06/2017 01/07/2017
6        B 01/06/2017 01/07/2017
7        C 01/06/2017 01/07/2017
8        D 01/06/2017 01/07/2017
> Records
  Location       Date Individuals
1        A 09/01/2017           3
2        A 12/01/2017           2
3        B 20/01/2017           6
4        C 06/06/2017           4
5        C 03/06/2017           0
6        C 19/01/2017           1
7        D 02/01/2017           6
```

I'm hoping to add a column to the survey data frame that sums the number of individuals that occurred at that site and within the relevant time period. The result looking like this:

```
Sum.Individuals <- c(5,6,1,6,0,0,4,0)
Final <- cbind(Surveys,Sum.Individuals)

> Final
  Location      Start        End Total.Individuals
1        A 01/01/2017 01/02/2017                 5
2        B 01/01/2017 01/02/2017                 6
3        C 01/01/2017 01/02/2017                 1
4        D 01/01/2017 01/02/2017                 6
5        A 01/06/2017 01/07/2017                 0
6        B 01/06/2017 01/07/2017                 0
7        C 01/06/2017 01/07/2017                 4
8        D 01/06/2017 01/07/2017                 0
```

I hope that makes sense, any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest the following steps:

1. joining both tables on location
2. filtering where Date is between Start and End
3. group by location, start, and end; sum individuals.

so could would be like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
df <- inner_join(surveys,records,by='Location')
df %<>% filter(Date >= Start, Date <= End)
df %<>% group_by(Location,Start,End) %>% summarise(totalindividuals=sum(individuals)
```

hope that helps. if you're finding the code confusing, you may wish to explore the concept of joining and filtering, and the `dplyr` package in general which is very relevant to these sort of tasks.

Comment: Hi, using that method I'm getting a frame of just one observation with the total of all cells. Also in my actual data the Records and Surveys frames are large with many additional variables so I'm not sure joining them will be feasible. Cheers

Comment: Subset to the columns you need before joining. You can use `data.table` for non-equi joins.